# Passing child nodes to a functional react component written typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

What's the correct way to pass child nodes using the `children` keyword in a React component written in typescript, when using named functions instead of arrow functions?

In an arrow function I can write something like this:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = ({children}) => {
   return <div>{children}</div>
}

export default MyComponent;
```

But how do I do the same thing with a `normal` function? I tried

```
import React from "react";

function MyComponent({children}): JSX.Element{
   return <div>{children}</div>
}

export default MyComponent;
```

But eslint throws the following error:

```
var children: any
Object pattern argument should be typed. eslint(@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types)
'children' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types)
```

I can get rid of the error by exporting `ReactNode` from React.

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react"

function MyComponent({children}: ReactNode): JSX.Element{
   return <div>{children}</div>
}

export default MyComponent;
```

But is this considered a viable way to go about this, or is there something else that's considered best practice?

Comment: best practice is arrow functions

Comment: Are they? I've been using arrow functions so far, but I've begun to doubt them as best practice after seeing both next.js omitting them from their examples and the react docs only using named functions. Would love to get some clarity on the topic. Here's an example from the next.js example repository: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter/components

Comment: There is a type `PropsWithChildren<P>` that you can import from React.  It's the same as adding `{children?: ReactNode}` to the props but perhaps it's more readable.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thank you! Did not know about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give the children param the correct type..

Something like this should work..

```js
function MyComponent({ children }: {children: React.ReactNode}): JSX.Element {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

Comment: This is correct but note that this makes `children` required.  Sometimes that is the desired behavior but it's more common to have it be an optional prop (as it is in the `React.FC` type) which would be `{children?: React.ReactNode}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a prop interface.

```
interface MyComponentProps {
   children: React.ReactNode
}
function MyComponent({ children }: MyComponentProps ): JSX.Element {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```